# In Directives Apply different css template while appending element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to design dynamic Menu , menu items will be loaded from json . and when menu clicked  i want to apply different template on them .

I was palnning to use Directives but i wonder how can i use template while appending Element in Controller .I want to use template beacuse i dont want hardcoded thing , i want to call template file.

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/simmi_simmi987/yw73K/)

**how can i pass attributes to template in above fiddle?**

Any other suuggestion please let me know !!

```
app.directive("helloWorld", function() {
 return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      name: "@name"
    },
    template: "<button ng-click='click()'>Click me</button>",
     controller: function($scope, $element){
         $scope.clicked = 0;
         $scope.click = function(){
           alert("Element clicked");
           $element.append('yes i did it');
         }
       }
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $http to download your template and after $compile to compile it:

```
app.directive("helloWorld", function($http, $compile) {
 return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      name: "@name"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $http.get("yourTemplate").then(function(template) {
          $compile(template)(scope);
          element.append(template);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks !! i will search about it . any reference from ur side ? also can u please remove downvote ...I am learner m just learning , i guess due to download i am not getting any help